# First-order differencing on multi-level categorical variables

Tags: panel-data, differences

I’m running a first-order differenced regression in Stata estimating the effect of the Covid-pandemic (categorical with 4 levels; 0 - 3) on the natural log of reported crime (continuous) on 290 panels. T = 58, monthly measures.

All of my predictors are multi-leveled categorical variables and two of them vary by time (the phases of Covid and a Seasonal indicator. The problem I face is that my professor told me that all variables should be differenced, including the categorical variables.

I understand that time-invariant variables are a bit unnecessary in a first-differenced regression, but I do not really see why I need to or even should difference time-variant categorical predictors as they do not indicate the time periods I’m interested in after differencing.

Does someone know if this is correct because it seems to me to be very counterintuitive?

I've been trying to find sources on first differening related to categorical variables but I havent found anyting.